# C# File.Exists seems to remember that the file existed

Tags: c#, file, move, exists

I'm currently working on a simple winforms renamer and I cannot find out how to fix IF containing !File.Exists, since when I press the second button and go back to the first one it will just do both the IF and ELSE and I have no idea why.

This is the code that is giving me a trouble:

```
string french = readpath + "\\data\\Fallout4 - Voices_fr.ba2";
string german = readpath + "\\data\\Fallout4 - Voices_de.ba2";
string voices = readpath + "\\data\\Fallout4 - Voices.ba2";
if (French.Checked)
{
    if (!File.Exists(german))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Move(voices, german);
            File.Move(french, voices);
            label1.Text = "Game set to French";
        }

        catch
        {
            label1.Text = "file doesn't exist";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Game already in French";
    }

}

if (German.Checked)
{
    if (!File.Exists(french))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Move(voices, french);
            File.Move(german, voices);
            label1.Text = "Game set to German";
        }

        catch
        {
            label1.Text = "file doesn't exist";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Game already in German";
    }
}
```

The code checks if German file doesn't exist and by that it determines that the voice file is currently in German so it tries to change to French, that works fine but when I do this multiple times between first IF and second IF it still renames the files fine but both the IF and ELSE complete which is weird to me, so the label just keeps on saying Game already in French/German depending on which radio I click.

Comment: Why not just always have the `_de` and `_fr` files and just copy that to the unsuffixed name based on which check box is ticked? Admittedly, you wouldn't be able to have your "game is already in ..." prompts but are they really that useful to you?

Comment: what control you are using button or radio button ??

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The game that I'm doing this for requires one file not having the _de/_fr extension for it to even launch so its required. The program works fine even with the label, I was just curious how to fix it since it seems very weird to me that its happening.

Comment: @PranayRana I'm using radio button

Comment: My point was - have all three files exist on disk. Then instead of moving one copy out of the way to make room for the other one, just *overwrite* the unsuffixed one with the language version you want to use.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah that would work, but it would require one more 3 GB file on the disk so I would rather not do it that way

Comment: If you have two radiobuttons mutually exclusive then you should change your _if(German.Checked)_ to a simple _else_

Comment: It is not possible for both conditions of a branch to be executed in the same thread. You have some other issue and it is not adequately described.

Comment: @Steve Oh, great idea thanks, although it still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Also- `if (File.Exists(german) ) { label1.Text = "Game already in French"; } ... ` seems like a mistake to me? Note that I inverted your order of branches and removed the inversion.

Comment: @theMayer Well, if there is another issue I can't seem to find it but so far it seems like both are executed, since my files are renamed properly and my label gets changed to the one it would be set to by the `ELSE` in the same branch.

Comment: Is the code being executed twice? What do you see when toss a mess of breakpoints in each leg and then step through the code?

Comment: @theMayer its `if (!File.Exists(german))` so it determines that the game is currently in German language by doing that

Comment: @JNevill Yeah, It seems like its being executed twice, but I have no idea what causes that

Comment: What if you stored the current language file name in a variable?  This way you only swap strings and setting the same language twice wouldn't result in moving a file twice.  A `Dictionary<string,string>` would work to pair up the language with the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in radios being executed twice, and not anything to do with File.Exists, thanks for all the help

Comment: So glad you figured this one out! Your code looked fine so it was a real head scratcher.